# как разбить url и вы вести все что после "?"

Tags: php

Допустим есть `url = https://.site.ru/index.php?id=5&v=3`, как вывести все что после `?` `$get = "id=5&v=3"`;

Comment: Я конечно понимаю метку PHP, но `url = https://.site.ru/index.php?id=5&v=3` не PHP формат, а вот второй кусок да.
Вы не пробовали зайти в доки по ПХП, они и на русском есть

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.parse-url.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, так

```
list(, $query) = explode('?', $url);
```

или так

```
$uqery = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ, так же пытался реализовать, но случайно сделал ошибку и не мог понять почему не работает, вот и за дался вопросом.
Спасибо, все работает

Answer (score 1):

`$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`, а вообще доки/мануалы рулят, к примеру http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.server.php или http://zarabotat-na-sajte.ru/uroki-php/3-ispolzovanie-metodov-get-i-post.html
или http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.get.php